# Java regexp in matcher input

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get quoted strings using regexp.

```
String regexp = "('([^\\\\']+|\\\\([btnfr\"'\\\\]|[0-3]?[0-7]{1,2}|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}))*'|\"([^\\\\\"]+|\\\\([btnfr\"'\\\\]|[0-3]?[0-7]{1,2}|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}))*\")";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher m = p.matcher(source); 
while (m.find()) {
    String newElement = m.group(1);
    //...
}
```

It works well, but if source text contains

`' onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/\D/, \'\')">'`

program goes into eternal loop.

How can I correctly get this string?

For example, I have a text(php code):

```
'qty'=>'<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="qty_text" id='.$key.' value ='
```

The result should be

```
'qty'
'<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="qty_text" id='
' value ='
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your goal here. Could you post some examples of your input -> output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex seems to work okay when presented with a string it matches; it's when it *can't* match that it goes into the endless loop.  (In this case it's the `\D` that's causing it to choke.)  But that regex is much more complicated than it needs to be; you're trying to *match* them, not validate them.  Here's the quintessential regex for a string literal in C-style languages:

```
"[^"\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^"\\\r\n]*)*"
```

...and the single-quoted version, for languages that support that style:

```
'[^'\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^'\\\r\n]*)*'
```

It uses Friedl's "unrolled loop" technique for maximum efficiency.  Here's the Java code for it, as generated by RegexBuddy 4:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "\"[^\"\\\\\r\n]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\\r\n]*)*\"|'[^'\\\\\r\n]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\\r\n]*)*'"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand the principle, but that looks rather trivial now that you added the example.

Consider this for instance:

```
String input = "'qty'=>'<input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"3\" class=\"qty_text\" id='.$key.' value ='";
String otherInput = "' onkeyup=\"this.value = this.value.replace (/\\D/, \'\')\">'";
// matching anything starting with single quote and ending with single quote 
// included, reluctant quantified
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'.+?'");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
m = p.matcher(otherInput);
System.out.println();
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
'qty'
'<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="qty_text" id='
' value ='

' onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/\D/, '
')">'
```

See the Java `Pattern` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more detailed explanations.

Comment: `'.*?'` will result in a truncated match for single-quoted string constants which contain an escaped single quote.

Comment: Yes, it's more comprehensible, but whether to use it depends on the input the OP wants to match with the regex.  If she just has a small input set she knows doesn't contain single quotes within single quoted strings, the minimal-match solution will do.  If it has to behave correctly when run against unknown input, she'll need a regex more like the original.

Answer (score 0):

The character groups that match neither backslashes nor quotes shouldn't be followed by a `+`.  Remove the `+`es to fix the hang (which was due to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)).

Also, your original regex wasn't recognizing `\D` as a valid backslash escape - therefore the string constant in your test input containing `\D` wasn't being matched.  If you make the rules of your regex more liberal to recognize any character immediately following a backslash as part of the string constant, it will behave the way you expect.

```
"('([^\\\\']|\\\\.)*'|\"([^\\\\\"]|\\\\.)*\")"
```

Comment: I try to delete `+`es, but from source string `'qty'=>'<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="qty_text" id='.$key.' value ='.$value.' onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/\D/, \'\')">'` I got result `['qty', '<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="qty_text" id=', ' value =', '\')">']`, but last match should be `' onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/\D/, \'\')">'`

Comment: That's because there's a bug in the original regex (it regards `\D` as invalid).  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in one line using `split()` with the right regex:

```
String[] array = source.replaceAll("^[^']+", "").split("(?<!\\G.)(?<=').*?(?='|$)");
```

There's a reasonable amount of regex kung fu going on here, so I'll break it down:

- The delimiter is wrapped by even/odd quotes, but can not *contain* the quotes because `split()` *consumes* the delimiter, so a look behind `(?<=')` and look ahead `(?=')` (which are non-consuming) is used to match the quotes instead of a literal quote in the regex
- a reluctant match `.*?` for characters between the quotes ensures that it stops at the next quote (instead of matching through to the last quote)
- I added an alternate match for end of input tot he look ahead `(?='|$)` in case there's no trailing close quote
- And saving the best for last, the regex that is key to making this all work is the negative look behind `(?<!\\G.)` which means "don't match on the end of the previous match" and ensures the next match advances past the end of the previous delimiter, without which you would end up with just the quote characters in your array. `\G` matches the *end* of the previous match, but also matches start of input for the first match, so it rather neatly automatically handles *not* matching on the first quote - thus making the delimiter wrapped in even/odd quote instead of odd/even as it would be otherwise.
- To cater for the input's first character not being a quote, you need to strip off the leading characters before splitting - that's why the `replaceAll()` is needed

---

Here's some test code using your sample input:

```
String source = "'qty'=>'<input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"3\" class=\"qty_text\" id='.$key.' value ='";
String[] array = source.replaceAll("^[^']+", "").split("(?<!\\G.)(?<=').*?(?='|$)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Output:

```
['qty', '<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="qty_text" id=', ' value =']
```

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation. For my example it works. I tested it with `$cart = $this->session->userdata('cart');
$this->load->view('footer');` I expected for result `['cart', 'footer']`. But the result I got was `$cart = $this->session->userdata('cart');
$this->load->view('footer');`

Comment: Did you read my whole answer, especially the second half about dealing with the input that doesn't start with a quote? My code works perfectly: It produces the result you want. To make it easier, I have edited my answer to assume that input does not start with a quote.

Comment: I've read it twice (or maybe more). Sorry, I made a mistake in 1st comment. Your code works fine, but fails if input contains `\n`. When `String source = "$cart = $this->session->userdata('cart');\n$this->load->view('footer');";` result was `['cart');
$this->load->view(', ');]`. I fixed it with `String[] array = source.replaceAll("^[^']+|[\\r\\n]", "").split("(?<!\\G.)(?<=').*?(?='|$)");`. Is it right way? Or should I use other regex to allow `\n` in string?

Comment: To handle newlines, try adding the "dot all" flag `(?s)` to the split regex: `replaceAll("^[^']+", "").split("(?s)(?<!\\G.)(?<=').*?(?='|$)")`. You shouldn't need to strip out newlines, however if that's the only way to get it to work, then it's fine.